# How to store parameter estimates from a for loop when the loop indexing is as 'cell' rather than values?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm running a for loop through each of my variables, i.e. through each column in a data table. The purpose of this for loop is to run a regression of each of the variables on some prespesified other variables. I want to save the parameter estimates of each regression, but I'm having trouble doing so because of the way the for loop is indexed. Any ideas?

```
m = [1 2 3 6 12 24 36 60 84 120 240 360]';
VarNames = data.Properties.VariableNames(1,[1:356]);
for v = VarNames
    for i=1:50
        current_column = v{1}
                t = i;
                data.X_1 = (1-exp(-m./t))./(m./t);
                data.X_2 = ((1-exp(-m./t))./(m./t))-exp(-m./t);

                model_spec = [current_column ' ~ X_1 + X_2'];
                model_1 = fitlm(data, model_spec);

                RSS(50,:) = zeros ;
                res = model_1.Residuals.Raw;
                res(any(isnan(res), 2), :) = [];
                RSS(i) = sum(res.^2);
    end 
    t = find(RSS(:,1) == min(RSS(:,1)));
    data.X_1 = (1-exp(-m./t))./(m./t);
    data.X_2 = ((1-exp(-m./t))./(m./t))-exp(-m./t);

    model_spec = [current_column ' ~ X_1 + X_2'];
    model_1 = fitlm(data, model_spec)

    intercept(v) = model_1.Coefficients.Estimate(1,1)

end
```

The last line of code is what causes the error. I need to save each of the 356 intercepts, slope-parameters and curvature-parameters in different vectors. But how do I achieve this when the loop is not on the form: for k = 1:100 (e.g.)?

I receive the following error message: Unable to use a value of type
'cell' as an index.

Comment: What about simply changing the loop to `for ix_v = 1:numel(VarNames)` and in the first line `v=VarNames{ix_v}`, then you got your index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only index with something numeric, so keep the loop index as numeric.

In this case, you just need to move the `current_column` assignment to the top of the loop and index into `VarNames`, with `v` being an index instead of a cell element.

```
m = [1 2 3 6 12 24 36 60 84 120 240 360]';
VarNames = data.Properties.VariableNames(1,[1:356]);
for v = 1:numel(VarNames) % loop over number of elements in VarNames
    current_column = VarNames{v}; % Get the varname for this loop
    for i=1:50
            t = i;
            data.X_1 = (1-exp(-m./t))./(m./t);
            data.X_2 = ((1-exp(-m./t))./(m./t))-exp(-m./t);

            model_spec = [current_column ' ~ X_1 + X_2'];
            model_1 = fitlm(data, model_spec);

            RSS(50,:) = zeros ;
            res = model_1.Residuals.Raw;
            res(any(isnan(res), 2), :) = [];
            RSS(i) = sum(res.^2);
    end 
    t = find(RSS(:,1) == min(RSS(:,1)));
    data.X_1 = (1-exp(-m./t))./(m./t);
    data.X_2 = ((1-exp(-m./t))./(m./t))-exp(-m./t);

    model_spec = [current_column ' ~ X_1 + X_2'];
    model_1 = fitlm(data, model_spec)

    intercept(v) = model_1.Coefficients.Estimate(1,1)    
end
```